# TCPDF convert inline SVG with html into PDF

Tags: php, pdf, svg, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to convert html into PDF.

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();       

    $html  = '<div>Some random html </div>';        
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('/pdf/output.pdf','F');
```

It works like a charm.

But I have a case when (Dynamic) html has SVG inline code also. So I need to convert this html which has SVG into PDF. But it does not work. Below is my code.

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();       

    $html  = '<div>Some random html <div style="width: 100px;"><svg viewBox="10 0 80 80">
    <ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
    <ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
    <ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
    </svg></div> </div>';        
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('/pdf/output.pdf','F');
```

So in this case the generated PDF has all the html printed in pdf but in place of SVG it says "Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG".

Is there any possible way to generate PDF from html containing SVG?

Update I found http://www.pdfy.net/  this website can convert html based svg into PDF. Any idea how they are doing it?

**EDIT 1:**

Okay Now I found that [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/) have supports for inline SVG. And it has really great support for it. **But**   mPDF have it's own problem of very less support for basic css. For Eg. Position absolute, float are not supported very well.

So again I am back with the same problem with additional requirement. A library which supports conversion of html with inline svg to PDF and it also supports all basic CSS.

Comment: Http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf has a drop in jquery plugin for PDF on remote site. It is using an XSL FO backend at the server. You would need to add SVG namespace to your sample.

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I have the same issue...?

Comment: For PHP still I have not found any solution. But I found a solution in JAVA and .NET [svg_to_pdf](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/svg_to_pdf_conversion.htm) I have not tried though.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution #1- Save `svg` to file**

You can save your `svg` part of your `HTML` into a file. Then you can add the `svg` image into your PDF with `$pdf->ImageSVG()` function as it says [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps).

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='path/to/testsvg.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);

$pdf->Write(0, $txt='', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

**Solution #2- Add inline `svg`**

You can store your inline `svg` into a variable (for example `$svgString`):

```
$svgString = '<svg viewBox="10 0 80 80">
<ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
<ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
<ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
</svg>';
```

Then you can add your `$svgString` variable to PDF like this:

```
$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svgString, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);

$pdf->Write(0, $txt='', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

Comment: Your second solution worked for me. Can you explain though why you add '@' in front of the svgstring?

Comment: @Daidon that will treat ur input as a string content (normally you'd input the name of the SVG file)

Comment: I tried this and it's working completely fine on few SVG images but in few errors occurred like `undefined index`.

Comment: It's weird that using `$border=2` throws `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Answer (score 1):

@Soroush

You have missed out only one statement which I am adding in your code, hope that will help, I tested and its working 100%.

```
    $svgString = '<svg viewBox="10 0 80 80">
    <ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:purple" />
    <ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:lime" />
    <ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15" style="fill:yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. 
    </svg>';

    $pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svgString, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='',         $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);  
    $pdf->Write(0, $txt='', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
    $pdf->Output('networth-and-cashflow-document.pdf', 'D'); // This will download PDF
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I think is to use ImageSVG "inside" your HTML code, using the tcpdf method TAG.

For the SVG, here is an example:

```
 // Create the SVG on a string
$svgString .= "<svg width=\"100\" height=\"100\">";
$svgString .= "<circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"green\" stroke-width=\"4\" fill=\"yellow\" />";
$svgString .= "</svg>";

// Prepare the parameters for the function
$params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('@' . $svgString, $x='', $y='', $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false));

// Declare the tag with the name of the function yu want to call and add the parameters
$tcpdf_start1 .= '<tcpdf method="ImageSVG" params="'.$params.'" />';

 // Prepare your HTML code inside of which you just insert the special TAG
$code_html  = "";
$code_html .= "<h1>My first SVG</h1>";
$code_html .= "<table border=\"1\">";
$code_html .= "<tr><td style=\"text-align: center;\">Top</td></tr>";
$code_html .= "<tr><td>".$tcpdf_start1."</td></tr>";
$code_html .= "</table>";

// Basicly produce your PDF with the parameters of your choice.
$pdf->writeHTML($code_html, $ln, $fill, $reseth, $cell, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with TCPDF could be, that it is possible to place svg's as  source attribute in HTML inlined.

If you look at the example 06 of TCPDF, that's how svg is inlined in $writeHTML: 
https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/95c5938aafe4b20df1454dbddb3e5005c0b26f64/examples/example_006.php#L112

With that you could either parse your html string, or change the source to match the syntax that will work in both browser and pdf (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#The_quick_way_).

Example with an SVG in image set as src:

```
$iconSpecialNeedsWhite = '/system/modules/assets/images/wheelchair-white.svg';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w[$i], $h, '', '', '<table cellpadding="6"><tr><td align="center"><img src="'.$iconSpecialNeedsWhite.'" height="12"/></td></tr></table>', 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
```

Comment: This is not going to work, SVG can be added only by using $pdf->ImageSVG() method

Comment: Of course it's going to work - I have this exact code working. TCPDF parses the img src attribute and if it's an svg will correctly add it to the pdf. I added a code example of how it works.