# SVG to PDF in php

Tags: php, pdf, svg

I have created a `PDF` using the `SVG` data.

```
try{
    $mpdf = new mPDF;
    $final_html = '<div>';
    //$raw_images contains the SVG Path
    foreach($raw_images as $rimage){
        $final_html .= "<img src='".$rimage."' width='100%'><br/><br/>";
    }
    $file_name = uniqid($prefix).".pdf";

    $final_html .= '</div>';
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($final_html);
    $mpdf->Output($folder_name.$file_name, 'F');

} catch (ImagickException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Please check this [Codepen For SVG](https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/QmLBmd)

Now the resulted PDF looks like this [View PDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AoXRRax7CxYvg2TZyHqNtZDOCbn1)

If you check the SVG data it contains one image with SVG.like `<image id="qr_code" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml...`. So SVG data has one svg image in it (means kind of svg inside svg).

SVG image woks fine, means you can view the output (i.e. QR code is visible). But the resulted PDF doesn't display the QR code (might be because QR code image is SVG).

So how to fix this issue, so QR code become visible in the PDF?

Comment: …or because you are using a BASE64 encoded SVG embedded inside a SVG embedded inside a PDF!? Why is it like that? Get rid of the superfluous complexity and test again. (btw SVG can be tranformed in to EPS, which is the default format for vector grahpics to be embedded in PDFs.)

Comment: Actually, i am making business card and its required to have QR code in it. So if i render the PNG file for QR code then that part of card is no longer vector. So that's why i have added QR code svg inside card svg.

Comment: You should not render the SVG, you just should try to avoid the nesting, and first of all the nesting in form of base64 encoded data. I don't what PDF makes out of it. It's just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/images.html

> Embedded image data can be used either in  elements or in CSS
>   background. gif, png and jpeg are supported.

So, SVG is not supported. Always read the documentation. A tip on the same page:

> mPDF partially supports SVG images, including as embedded HTML

Comment: is there any way to created PDF using svg data, so resulted pdf can have all kind of svg image/object etc.?

Comment: If you are not restricted to use mPDF then TCPDF library might be a solution. Like here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876116/tcpdf-convert-inline-svg-with-html-into-pdf